# How to integrate jsreport in electron project?

Tags: node.js, electron, jsreport

I am working on electron app and i need to integrate to it a tool for reporting like jsreport. 
Can someone help me to find a link that explain how to integrate Jsreport into electron app?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing some research and i found a post in the blog of jsreport talking about it, this  the post
https://jsreport.net/blog/using-electron-to-create-pdf-reports

And this is the repo in github where they explain how to install and use it.
https://github.com/bjrmatos/jsreport-electron-pdf

I haven't tested it yet but i hope it help you.